# Consuming java written webservices without adding web reference in c#

Tags: c#, apache, web-services, webrequest

how to Consume java(apache axis) written webservices without adding **web reference(in visual studio)** in c#

Comment: plz help me to solve this problem

Answer (score 0):

If your AXIS service provide WSDL you can dynamically compile proxies and invoke via reflection without any of web reference magic.